# Bootstrap popup jQuery and validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have two jQuery libraries; first one is for Bootstrap popup, and second one is for normal jQuery use.

first one :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

second one :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So is there any jQuery library which works for both? My code got conflicted when used both together with jQuery validate.

Comment: You do not need two versions of jQuery!  The latest version of jQuery Validate plugin will work just fine with version 1.12.4 of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [jQuery DOC: no conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

EDIT (after comments):

about your error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, make sure:

- jQuery is properly loaded **first** on the page
- no script is trying to run before page is loaded -> `$(document).ready(function () { /* your code */ });`

Comment: **why** would you use such an *old outdated version* such as 1.7 though ? no way you use only one, the latest ? the doc clearly says `(which is not recommended)`

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  i used this version but problem do not get solved

Comment: now that you use only one, what is the problem ? modal not showing ? other ? what does console say when you run a function ? any error ?

Comment: i got this error,  "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: I'd suggest you open a new Q with the code throwing error, explaining you went from 2 libraries to one and getting this error, with the problem code

Comment: You do not need two versions of jQuery!  The latest version of the jQuery Validate plugin will work just fine with version 1.12.4 of jQuery.